# SSL certificate and "www" vs non "www"

Tags: ssl

I'm being asked to redirect a website to https once an SSL certificate is installed. It's a wordpress site and this should be very easy, you simply go to settings and change the http to https, and/or install a plugin to manage everything for you and change all of the "http" in your files for "https".

The certifiate came with problems that the host fixed gradually (it wouldn't pass any test on qualys SSL Labs). However for some reason they sent me an e-mail stating that the certificate is made for the "www version of the site". this site didn't have "www" in it's address.

The non "www" version now redirects to the "www" version but I just cannot get a green padlock. Oddly enough, I did get one refreshing the page a few times and when I did it was all messed up. If I check the page source some stylesheet links for example look for the https:// no www version of the page and this is probably the problem right?

Should I just change manually all of the links in the page or ask the host not to create a certificate for a www version of this website when it didn't have that in the first place?

/* EDIT */

I get this in the console before an error for every single url in the page for images and stylesheets, etc.

Redirecting navigation because the server presented a certificate valid for www... but not for "non www version" To disable such redirects launch Chrome with the following flag: ...

Comment: Maybe you didn't install the certificate bundle with all the intermediate ca's.

Comment: I didn't install the certificate, the host did. I simply had to do the redirects. But they added the "www" for some reason and this has created a lot of problems now.

Comment: Some ca`s like geotrust for instance sign a csr for www and non-www if you provide a common name with www included in your csr.  This can maybe solve your issue.